# python randrange duplicates selection

Tags: python, unique, random

How can I make sure the value returned is unique each time in python? I am using random.randrange like so -

```
batter = ("Sammy Slammer","Lonnie Longball","Billy Bomber","Jack Runs","Ricky Redic",)
bnum = random.randrange(0,5)
upnow = batter[bnum]
```

Which works except I get duplicates often..

Tried this thanks to @Fabricator -

```
batter = ("Sammy Slammer","Lonnie Longball","Billy Bomber","Jack Runs","Ricky Redic",)
bnum = random.randrange(0,5)
upnow = batter[bnum]
l = list(batter)
random.shuffle(l)
for upnow in l:
print upnow
```

And -

```
batter = ("Sammy Slammer","Lonnie Longball","Billy Bomber","Jack Runs","Ricky Redic",)
l = list(batter)
random.shuffle(l)
for upnow in l:
print upnow
```

The error im getting refferes to my sqlite 3 statement -

"for i in reversed (xrange)1,len(x) int has no len()"

I shortened the code up, the sqlite3 works fine without the shuffle..

```
    bbatter_ai =  (brow["BATTER"])
tab = cab_ai + at_bat
conn.execute("UPDATE batter set AB = ? WHERE BATTER = ?",[tab] + [bbatter_ai])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can shuffle the list of players:

```
l = list(batter)
random.shuffle(l)
for upnow in l:
    print upnow
```

IDLE:

```
In [1]: import random

In [2]: batter = ("Sammy Slammer","Lonnie Longball","Billy Bomber","Jack Runs","Ricky Redic",)

In [3]: l = list(batter)

In [4]: random.shuffle(l)

In [5]: for upnow in l:
   ...:     print upnow
   ...:     
Jack Runs
Sammy Slammer
Lonnie Longball
Billy Bomber
Ricky Redic
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, this throws the error "for i in reversed (xrange)1,len(x) int has no len()"

Comment: @RyanD, please post your new code. it's appears to be unrelated to my answer

Comment: @RyanD, just posted my IDLE session, I can't reproduce your error

Comment: I think my error is related to my sqlite3 statement -